# Too many decimal places when using timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, timedelta

I am trying to find the time in hour and minutes however, the only way I know how to do it is by using what I have done below. Below is also my output and as you can see, it the program returns seconds along with decimals after.

CODE:

```
def commercial_time (distance, speed_of_commercial):
    time = distance / speed_of_commercial
    seconds = time * 3600
    real = (datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds))
    return real
```

OUTPUT:

```
9:46:04.352515
```

My question is, is there a way I can get rid of that ".352515"? 
I would also like to hide the seconds as well if that is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Format the `timedelta` manually:

```
def custom_format(td):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> def custom_format(td):
...     minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 60)
...     hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
...     return '{:d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes)
... 
>>> custom_format(timedelta(hours=9, minutes=46, seconds=4, microseconds=352515))
'9:46'
```

This method *does* ignore the `.days` attribute. If you have timedeltas with more than 24 hours, use:

```
def custom_format(td):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    formatted = '{:d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes)
    if td.days:
        formatted = '{} day{} {}'.format(
            td.days, 's' if td.days > 1 else '', formatted)
    return formatted
```

Demo:

```
>>> custom_format(timedelta(days=42, hours=9, minutes=46, seconds=4, microseconds=352515))
'42 days 9:46'
>>> custom_format(timedelta(days=1, hours=9, minutes=46, seconds=4, microseconds=352515))
'1 day 9:46'
>>> custom_format(timedelta(hours=9, minutes=46, seconds=4, microseconds=352515))
'9:46'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Very simple solution

```py
from datetime import timedelta

def format_seconds(seconds: float, decimal_places: int = 2):
    return str(timedelta(seconds=seconds))[: -6 + decimal_places]
```

```py
>>> format_seconds(123.1234123123) 
'0:02:03.12'
>>> format_seconds(123.0999999999)  
'0:02:03.10'
>>> format_seconds(123.0999999999, decimal_places=4) 
'0:02:03.1000'
>>> format_seconds(123.1234124, decimal_places=4)    
'0:02:03.1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timedifference to a string with `str()`, then separate on either side of the decimal place with `.split('.')`. Then keep the first portion before the decimal place with `[0]`:

Your example with the only difference on the last line:

```
import time
import datetime

def commercial_time (distance, speed_of_commercial):
    time = distance / speed_of_commercial
    seconds = time * 3600
    real = (datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds))
    return str(real).split('.')[0]
```

then:

```
print( commercial_time( 10 , 1.025 ) )
```

generates:

```
9:45:21
```